# How does the scanf() function work in assembly code?

Tags: assembly, scanf, sparc

I am new to assembly coding and I am trying figure out how the scanf function works. I just want to take the integer of the user input and add 5 to it and print that out. I can't get it to work and this is what I have so far. I tried just printing the user input by itself and I still can't get it to work.

Can someone explain to me the process?

```
.section ".data"
prompt: .asciz "\nEnter a number: "
format: .asciz "%d"
format2: .asciz "Your number plus 5 is: %d"
input: .word 0
nl: .asciz "\n"


define(a1, 5)

.align 4
.section ".text"
.global main
main:
save %sp, -96, %sp



!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  Prompt the user for a number
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

set   prompt, %o0            !point o0 to the prompt
call  printf                 !call printf to print the prompt
nop

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!  uses scanf to store the integer in register o1
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

set   format, %o0            !address of the format
set   input, %o1             !address of the location for the max
set   nl, %o2
call  scanf                  !reads user input, coverts to a
nop                          !number and stores at the memory referenced by input


!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!Prints out the integer plus 5
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

set   format2, %o0
set   input, %o1
ld    [%o1], %o1             
add   %o1, %a1, %o1           
call   printf
nop


ret
restore
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`define(a1, 5)` most probably does a simple text substitution, as such `add %o1, %a1, %o1` will be assembled as `add %o1, %5, %o1` whereby `%5` will resolve to register number 5 which is `%g5` and not what you want. Solution: just use `add %o1, 5, %o1` or give some other symbolic name to the constant and use that without a `%` sign. The rest looks about right, except for the extra, but harmless, argument you pass to `scanf` (`set nl, %o2`).

Hint: saying "*urgent*" won't get you any faster replies, but providing more details, such as what the exact problem is, could.

Comment: Im still getting a "Bus error (core dumped)" after making the correction you suggested and even commenting out the set n1, %o2. Do you have any idea? is there a problem with the ld command?

Comment: See, if you tell me you get a bus error, I can help you: it's probably due to the `input` variable not being word aligned. Use whatever alignment directive your assembler has to make it 4 byte aligned (e.g. place `.align 4` directly before it) or maybe even just allocate it from the stack which is known to be aligned.